# Is there a way in Spring to autowire all dependencies of a given type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I'm using annotations-based wiring (ie `@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE)`) for a given class, and I'd like to wire all beans of a given type into it as a list:

application context:

```
<beans>
    <bean class="com.my.class.FirstConfigurer"/>
    <bean class="com.my.class.SecondConfigurer"/>
</beans>
```

class to autowire into:

```
@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE) public class Target {
    ...
    public void setConfigurers(List<Configurer> configurers) { ... }
}
```

All dependencies implement a common interface called `Configurer`

Is there a way to make this work to have all dependencies of a type wired together in a collection and injected where necessary, or should I define a `<list>` in XML or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes,

```
@Inject
private List<Configurer> configurers;
```

works, and you get a list of all beans implementing the interface. (multiple variations - `@Inject` or `@Autowired`, field, setter or constructor injection - all work)

Comment: I've never been able to get field autowiring working, but good to know!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE) 
public class Target {

    @Autowired
    public void setConfigurers(List<Configurer> configurers) { ... }

}
```

This is described in [section 3.9.2 of the Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation):

> It is also possible to provide all beans of a particular type from the ApplicationContext by adding the annotation to a field or method that expects an array of that type [...] The same applies for typed collections.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working for me. I'm running Spring 3.0.1, I have configurable defined on my target class, autowired defined on my setter, load-time-weaving configured properly, configurer instances loaded in my application context, but no autowiring happens for this property, though other properties are autowired properly. Weird. I can see that Spring is creating the configurer in my app-context, but when autowiring comes, it doesn't include it. Do I need more than one for it to work?