# Spring not autowiring a collection via the load-time weaver

Tags: java, spring

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083308/is-there-a-way-in-spring-to-autowire-all-dependencies-of-a-given-type) question, it seems that you can declare something like the following and have it "work":

```
@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class Target {

    private List<Dependency> dependencies;

    public List<Dependency> getDependencies() {
        return this.dependencies;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDependencies(List<Dependency> dependencies) {
        this.dependencies = dependencies;
    }
}
```

Application context:

```
<beans>
    <!-- where all extend Dependency -->
    <bean class="com.dependencies.SubDependency"/>
    <bean class="com.dependencies.SubSubDependency"/>
</beans>
```

According to the manual, this should "just work™", but it doesn't. Other dependenices are wired on `Target` but the list dependency isn't. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I only have one dependency at the moment to be wired, but this will expand with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an example of doing this with build-time weaving on github. If it's not a problem with your weaver, maybe you can identify the problem by comparison. You can [browse it](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/spring-aspectj-build-time-weaving) or clone and run it:

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp
cd tmp
mvn -q compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=rds.spring.SpringConfigurable \
    -pl spring-aspectj-build-time-weaving
```

Comment: Even using compile time weaving doesn't do the trick, unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't do what trick? In my example, the List dependency is correctly populated with both beans of the given type.

Comment: It doesn't work, even after adding the compile time weaving :(

Comment: Do you have `<context:spring-configured/>` in a context file somewhere?

Comment: My bad, forgot to implement the requested interface in my abstract superclass. Epic fail.

Comment: @TK: It always happens where you're not looking :)

Comment: And it happens even more when you are... \*facepalm\*